# How to draw Custom View Extending Relative Layout to a canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have my main activity which creates an instance of SurfaceView. In the SurfaceView I am creating several simple objects from bitmaps. I pass a canvas element to them (objectX.draw(canvas)...etc) from a render method in the SurfaceView. all of this is working as i would like, however I would like to do the same with a custom RelativeLayout.

For example i would like to create a custom class extending RelativeLayout and fill it with various objects such as ImageView etc and then from the SurfaceView call a method which draws this to the canvas.

I have been looking for tutorials to help me understand how to do this but cannot find anything. I understand that I have to draw a bitmap of the RelativeLayout and then in turn draw that to my canvas which the surface view is passing in to it. I think a lot of my issues may be coming from the fact that i am not trying to ever add the Custom RelativeLayout to the screen, instead I would like to create it by inflating an xml layout and simply drawing to a passed in canvas.

Comment: you are drawing a ViewGroup from dispatchDraw method

Comment: what is the difference between onDraw() and dispatchDraw(). as far as I'm aware they are both called when the instance is added to the screen?

Comment: for ordinary Views yes, but for ViewGroup onDraw by default is not called, you can change it though, see ViewGroup docs